# Как работает Kafka и RabbitMQ через NAT

Tags: rabbitmq, nat, apache-kafka

Доброго времени суток!

Я разрабатываю распределенное приложение. Необходимо выбрать систему для обмена сообщениями. Выбор пал между Kafka и RabbitMQ.

У меня возник как будет работать мое приложение в серой сети. Когда приходит сообщение оно будет рассылаться всем узлам в серой сети так как не знает кому оно предназначено.

Каким образом в Kafka и RabbitMQ реализована отправка сообщения только определенному узлу в серой сети?